# C++ Lambda to Function Pointer

Tags: c++, function, c++11, pointers

I have three classes:

```
class ShapeEditor {}
class PointEditor: ShapeEditor{}
class RectEditor: ShapeEditor{}
```

I want to define a function pointer in `Manager` class and pass it in constructor as lambda function. It looks like this:

```
class Manager {
public:
  ShapeEditor (*factory)();
  Manager(ShapeEditor (*_factory)());
}
```

Then I'm writing in main:

```
Manager m = Manager([] { return PointEditor(); }
```

and getting an error message that there is no constructor for this expression.

When I changes `ShapeEditor` to `PointEditor` in `Manager` - it works fine, but I need to specify different types in function result.

Comment: If you do `return PointEditor()` in your lambda, is it a function that returns a `ShapeEditor`?

Comment: Beware of returning derived types by value as base types. You will encounter [Object Slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

Comment: Note that class definitions end with a semicolon. Also note that by default class inheritance is `private`.

Comment: @NathanOliver, If I correctly understand your question: PointEditor is derived from ShapeEditor. If I define a method in class like ShapeEditor foo() { return PointEditor()} - it will work.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I know, thank you, but this is not relevant to the subject of the question, so I have simplified the code in the example

Comment: Yes, but you didn't specify a return type for the lambda, so it gets it from the returned object, and that object doesn't have the same type as the return type your function pointer needs

Comment: `PointEditor(*)()` is unrelated to `ShapeEditor(*)()` and can't be converted to it. A much smaller example: `struct A {}; struct B : A{}; B f(); A (*g)() = f;`.

Comment: @GeorgeBublyk It is relevant to the question. When code contains syntax errors like these, it is not clear what error is related to what you are actually asking and what error is a result of lazy code writing. For example, the fact that you have `private` inheritance will prevent any kind of  conversion which is required to achieve what you want. If that is not the actual cause of the problem, then it is hiding the real cause.

Comment: @NathanOliver, yeah, this is the right answer. Thank you!

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, okay, you're right, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@NathanOliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4342498/nathanoliver) gave the correct answer in comments above:

> Yes, but you didn't specify a return type for the lambda, so it gets it from the returned object, and that object doesn't have the same type as the return type your function pointer needs

So here is my solution:

```
Manager m = Manager([] -> ShapeEditor* { return new PointEditor(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your lambda returns object value of type `ShapeEditor` which inherits from `ShapeEditor` and base class value is expected.

Basically you are expecting some kind of polymorphism, but you return value of some specific child type when you expect value for base type! This leads to silent conversion and as a result behavior is different then you expect so your answer is incorrect.

If you need polymorphism you need use a pointer or reference:

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class ShapeEditor {
public:
    virtual ~ShapeEditor() {}
    virtual std::string doSomething() = 0;
};

class PointEditor: public ShapeEditor {
public:
    std::string doSomething() override;
};

class RectEditor: public ShapeEditor{
public:
    std::string doSomething() override;
};

using ShapeEditorPtr = std::unique_ptr<ShapeEditor>;

class Manager {
public:
  ShapeEditorPtr (*factory)();

  Manager(ShapeEditorPtr (*_factory)());
};

void test() {
    Manager m = Manager([]() -> ShapeEditorPtr { 
        return std::make_unique<PointEditor>();
    });
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xP4czj

Answer (score 0):

as I can see that your problem is to try casting a `PointEditor` instance into a `ShapeEditor` instance. You need to cast Pointers, instead of values. So, in your lambda expression, you are returning a COPY of local instance `PointEditor` and trying to copy it into a `ShapeEditor` local variable.

Here is my proposal:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ShapeEditor {
public:
    virtual void printName(){};
};

class PointEditor: ShapeEditor{
    
public:
    void printName(){cout << "PointEditor\n";};
};

class RectEditor: ShapeEditor{
    
public:
    void printName(){cout << "RectEditor\n";};
};

class Manager {
    ShapeEditor* shp;
    ShapeEditor* (*factory) ();
public:
    Manager( ShapeEditor* (*_factory)() ):factory{_factory}{
        shp = factory();
        shp->printName();
    };
    
    ~Manager(){delete shp;}
};

int main()
{
    
    ShapeEditor* (*func1)() = [](){
        PointEditor* x = new PointEditor();
        ShapeEditor* s = (ShapeEditor*)x;
        return s;
        
    };
    
    ShapeEditor* (*func2)() = [](){
        RectEditor* x = new RectEditor();
        ShapeEditor* s = (ShapeEditor*)x;
        return s;
    };
    
    Manager m1 = Manager(func1);
    Manager m2 = Manager(func2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

the output:

```
PointEditor
RectEditor
```